# Easy to use js library for flexible time line charts

Tags: javascript, charts, analytics, linechart

I want a js library that will take in a set of epoch timestamps, and allow me to set the date range and step size (day, week, month) of a line chart generated from this data set. Very similar to how Mixpanel or Google Analytics works. Ideally all this functionality is pre-built, I just need to supply an array of epoch timestamps. Does anything like this exist?

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar research for my realtime charting project. At the end I found below 3 js libraries to suit my need.

1. [Epoch](https://fastly.github.io/epoch/): Use this if you want only basic charting functionality. Very Easy to use and integrate into your solution. This doesnot provide grouping functionality yet and misses few "must" configuration like "animation speed", "define specific domain & range" etc.
2. [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/): This also takes epoch timestamp as input and is having very advanced charting functions specially if you want to group data into days, weeks, months etc
3. [Amcharts](http://www.amcharts.com/): This also consists of advance charting functionalities but instead of epoch take timestamp as input.

Answer (score -1):

Google charts has a [date range slider](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#daterangefilter) which lets you do this.